# How to align image as pseudo element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```
<a class='flink'href='mc/index.php'>
<div class='cap_01'>323232323232</div>
<div class='cap_02'>52525252525252</div>
</a>
```

css

```
.cap_01:before{
    content: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c191bbf22d56f27dd1bc0128ea3b2844?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
    margin-right:9px;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
.cap_02{
    margin:5px 0 0 29px;
}
```

How can I adjust image in `cap_01:before` to be in the vertical middle with the text `323...` ?

JSFIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/59Etx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the pseudo element.